# Structural induction proof of substitution using semantics from "While" language

Tags: formal-languages

Hello I am currently self-studying the book "Semantics with applications: An Appetizer" and I don't know if I've gotten the right base case for the problem below:

Prove that $\mathcal{A} [[ a\left[y \mapsto a_0\right] ]] s=\mathcal{A} [[ a ]]\left(s\left[y \mapsto \mathcal{A} [[ a_0 ]] s\right]\right)$ for all states $s$.

So i think I have to prove this using structural induction. For the base case $a=n$, I get:
$\mathcal{A} [[ a\left[y \mapsto a_0\right] ]] = A[[n]] = n$ and $\mathcal{A} [[ a ]]\left(s\left[y \mapsto \mathcal{A} [[ a_0 ]] s\right]\right) = A[[n]] = n$

My question: Is my base case for this proof correct?

Here is some background information:
This book is based on the "While" language and I will put the semantics below.

[Semantics of arithmetic expressions (Aexp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuUkW.png)

[Semantics of substitution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Its.png)

Language semantics: [semantics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaSuX.png)

Definition of total function A: [total function A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqe4N.png)